# Swift 2 Reflection Error

Tags: reflection, swift2, mirror, xcode7.3

I have look around a swift code to try and make a reflection function that serialized an object into JSON. The trouble is when i call the initializer to get the reflection it throws a crazy error

```
struct Address {
    var street: String
}

struct Person {
    var name: String = "Dre"
    var age: Int = 33
    var dutch: Bool = false
    var address: Address? = Address(street: "Clark Drive")
}

// Throws an error on the next line
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: Person)
```

When i try to set the value of mirror to the result of Mirror initialization i get the following errors:

> 1. Missing argument label 'reflecting:' in call
> 2. Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of `Person` instead of the class `Person`. E.g:

```
struct Address {
    var street: String
}

struct Person {
    var name: String = "Dre"
    var age: Int = 33
    var dutch: Bool = false
    var address: Address? = Address(street: "Clark Drive")
}

let person = Person()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: person)

print(mirror.displayStyle)
for case let (label?, value) in mirror.children {
    print(label, value)
}
```

Prints:

```
Optional(Struct)
name Dre
age 33
dutch false
address Optional(Address(street: "Clark Drive"))
Mirror for Bookmark
```

Answer (score 3):

wrong:

```
func jediGreet(name: String, ability: String) -> (farewell: String, mayTheForceBeWithYou: String) {
  return ("Good bye, \(name).", " May the \(ability) be with you.")
}

let retValue = jediGreet("old friend", "Force")
println(retValue)
println(retValue.farewell)
println(retValue.mayTheForceBeWithYou)
```

correct:

```
func jediGreet(name: String, ability: String) -> (farewell: String, mayTheForceBeWithYou: String) {
  return ("Good bye, \(name).", " May the \(ability) be with you.")
}

let retValue = jediGreet (name:"old friend",ability: "Force")
print(retValue)
print(retValue.farewell)
print(retValue.mayTheForceBeWithYou)
```

Comment: I corrected the formatting for you. Now it's up to you to describe _what_ you changed and _why_